# how to insert dynamic html in the page?

Tags: node.js, typescript, next.js

i'm trying to make it work with `parser` from `html-react-parser` module but what i'm getting the error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

Warning: Expected server HTML to contain a matching <p> in <p>.

See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
```

I'm using `getServerSideProps` in this page since i read stuff from database into the component. my code goes as following:

```
interface IArgs
{
    articleData: IArticleResult;
}

const ArticleBox = (props: IArgs) =>
{
    const res = props.articleData;

    if(res.status == 'FAILED') {
        return <Alert severity="error">article failed to read</Alert>
    }

    const article:IArticle = res.result!;

    return (
        <>
            <ArticleTitle title={article.title} />
            <ArticleText text={article.contents}>
              {parser(article.contents)}
            </ArticleText>
        </>
    )
}

export default ArticleBox;
```

and the component that uses `parser`:

```
interface IProps {
  result: IArticleResult;
}

const View = (props: IProps) => {

  const data = props.result;
  
  return (
    <>
       <ArticleBox articleData={data} />
    </>
)

export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<{result: IArticleResult}> = async (context) => {
  const { params, req, res } = context;
  const id: string = Array.isArray(params?.id) ? params!.id[0] : (params?.id ?? "");
  
  if(id.length === 0) {
    return {
      notFound: true
    }
  }

  try
  {
    const res: IArticleResult = await fetchArticle({req: req, id: id});
    
    if(res.status == 'NO_RECORDS') {
      return {
        notFound: true
      }
    }

    return {
      props: {
        result: res,
      },
    };
  }
  catch(error)
  {
    // log to file
    logger.error('An error occurred while fetching article', error);
    res.statusCode = 500;
    return {
      props: {
        result: {
          status: 'FAILED',
          message: 'An error occurred while fetching article',
          httpCode: 500
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

interface IFetchArgs
{
  req: IncomingMessage;
  id: string;
}

const fetchArticle = async (args: IFetchArgs): Promise<IArticleResult> => {
    
    if(isNullOrEmpty(args.id)) {
      throw new ArgumentNullOrEmpty(nameof<IFetchArgs>("id"));
    }

    const { origin } = absoluteUrl(args.req);
    const response = await fetch(`${origin}/api/read_article?id=${args.id}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    //console.log('data = ', data);
    return data;
}

export default View;
```

where `article.contents`  hold a string with the HTML

**UPDATE**

By now, i'm using [`this`](https://traviswimer.com/blog/error-hydration-failed-because-the-initial-ui-does-not-match-what-was-rendered-on-the-server/) but I think it's hacky, so i'm open to alternatives:

```
interface IProps2
{
    text: string;
}

const ArticleText = (props: IProps2) => {

  const [initialRenderComplete, setInitialRenderComplete] = useState(false);

  // This useEffect will only run once, during the first render
    useEffect(() => {
        // Updating a state causes a re-render
        setInitialRenderComplete(true);
    }, []);

  if (!initialRenderComplete) {
    return null;
  }

    return (
      <Typography variant="body1">
        {parser(props.text)}
      </Typography>
    );
  };
```